# How to differentiate between 'local' and 'social' user types after login via Azure AD B2C?

Tags: node.js, azure-web-app-service, azure-ad-b2c

I have a Node.js/Express application that uses Azure AD B2C for authentication.

Currently, two types of users can login:

- Local accounts - `EXTERNAL` users in the Azure AD B2C tenant
- Social accounts - `INTERNAL` users from a single Azure AD tenant

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to display different frontend user interface elements based on the type of user that has logged in.

- Local accounts will be able to call endpoints relevant to `EXTERNAL` users
- Social accounts will be able to call endpoints relevant to `INTERNAL` users

What is the recommended way to differentiate between who logged in?

I can see that the `authToken` object that is returned from msal-node's [acquireTokenByCode() method](https://azuread.github.io/microsoft-authentication-library-for-js/ref/classes/_azure_msal_node.confidentialclientapplication.html#acquiretokenbycode) is different depending on which type of user logged in.

Should I use a property from the `authToken` object to differentiate between user types?

If so, which property is the best one to use?

And, so that I can perform relevant UI actions accordingly, is it acceptable to store this value as a cookie in the browser (eg `'user_type': 'EXTERNAL'` or `'user_type': 'INTERNAL'`) using something like [js-cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie)?

Below is a redacted version of the `authToken` object that is returned after login.

All values are the same for different users types, unless otherwise specified.

Notably, these two properties are only present after a 'social account' login:

- `idp_access_token`
- `idp`

```json
{
    "authority": "https://<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/b2c_1_signin1/",
    "uniqueId": "*******",  // <-- different for each user, this is the object id of the user as represented in the Azure AD B2C tenant
    "tenantId": "",
    "scopes":
    [
        "https://<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/my-web-app-api/tasks.write", // <-- these are the api permissions granted to my web app
        "https://<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.onmicrosoft.com/my-web-app-api/tasks.read"  // <-- these are the api permissions granted to my web app
    ],
    "account":
    {
        "homeAccountId": "***uniqueId***-b2c_1_signin1.<the-directory-id-of-my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>", // unique id is different for each user  
        "environment": "<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com",
        "tenantId": "",
        "username": "<user-email-address>", // different for each user  
        "localAccountId": "***uniqueId***", // different for each user  
        "idTokenClaims":
        {
            "exp": 1673069519,
            "nbf": 1673065919,
            "ver": "1.0",
            "iss": "https://<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<the-directory-id-of-my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>/v2.0/",
            "sub": "***uniqueId***", // different for each user  
            "aud": "<the-application/client id of my web app>",
            "iat": 1673065919,
            "auth_time": 1673065918,
            "idp_access_token": "********", // <-- this property is ONLY present in the authToken returned from the SOCIAL login  
            "idp": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<the-directory-id-of-my-azure-ad-tenant>/v2.0", // <-- this property is ONLY present in the authToken returned from the SOCIAL login  
            "emails":
            [
                "<user-email-address>" // different for each user  
            ],
            "tfp": "B2C_1_signin1",
            "at_hash": "*******" // different for each user  
        }
    },
    "idToken": "*******", // different for each user  
    "idTokenClaims":
    {
        "exp": 1673069519,
        "nbf": 1673065919,
        "ver": "1.0",
        "iss": "https://<my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>.b2clogin.com/<the-directory-id-of-my-azure-ad-b2c-tenant>/v2.0/",
        "sub": "***uniqueId***", // different for each user  
        "aud": "<the-application/client id of my web app>",
        "iat": 1673065919,
        "auth_time": 1673065918,
        "idp_access_token": "********", // <-- this property is ONLY present in the authToken returned from the SOCIAL login  
        "idp": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<the-directory-id-of-my-azure-ad-tenant>/v2.0", // <-- this property is ONLY present in the authToken returned from the SOCIAL login  
        "emails":
        [
            "<user-email-address>" // different for each user  
        ],
        "tfp": "B2C_1_signin1", // different for each user  
        "at_hash": "*******"
    },
    "accessToken": "*******", // different for each user  
    "fromCache": false,
    "expiresOn": "2023-01-07T05:31:57.000Z",
    "correlationId": "*******", // different for each user  
    "requestId": "",
    "extExpiresOn": "2023-01-07T05:31:57.000Z",
    "familyId": "",
    "tokenType": "Bearer",
    "state": "",
    "cloudGraphHostName": "",
    "msGraphHost": "",
    "fromNativeBroker": false
}
```

**For Reference**

For reference, below are the steps I took to:

- Enable login from a single Azure AD tenant
- Enable Azure AD users to be able to call Graph API in their own tenant

I added a single Azure AD tenant as an Identity Provider by going to:

`Azure Portal` > `Azure AD B2C Tenant` > `Azure AD B2C` > `Identity Providers` > `+ New OpenID Connect provider` > `[ fill in required fields and click 'Save' ]`

Detailed steps on adding an Azure AD tenant as an identity provider can be found here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow#configure-azure-ad-as-an-identity-provider

In the `Scope` field, I added the scopes that I wanted the Azure AD users to be able to use in their own tenant, i.e:

```
openid profile User.ReadWrite.All Directory.ReadWrite.All Team.ReadBasic.All TeamSettings.ReadWrite.All
```

Then I went to the relevant 'user flow' at:

`Azure Portal` > `Azure AD B2C Tenant` > `Azure AD B2C` > `User flows` > `B2C_1_signin1` > `Identity providers` > `[ check the recently added OpenID connect provider ]` > `[ click 'Save' ]`

In order for Azure AD users to be able to make Graph API calls to their own tenant, I did the following to make sure that an `idp_token` was returned when they logged in - I believe this is essentially an 'access token' for their tenant:

`Azure Portal` > `Azure AD B2C Tenant` > `Azure AD B2C` > `User flows` > `B2C_1_signin1` > `Application claims` > `[ select 'Identity Provider Access Token' ]` > `[ click 'Save' ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `idp` claim is the one that you are looking for since it will be set of all external providers of the Azure AD B2C tenant.

Note that the `idp_access_token` claim is present when [pass through](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow) is enabled but is only supported for OAuth 2.0 providers, so it may be blank for some.

Comment: Thank you for this insight, can I please clarify the second sentence, I am just confused about this part of the sentence "...the `idp_access_token` claim is present when pass through is enabled *BUT* is supported for OAuth 2.0 providers, so it *MAY* just be blank for some".  Perhaps there is a word missing somewhere?  Thank you.

Comment: Yes. I meant that only OAuth2.0 providers are supported when including the `idp_access_token` claim. For other providers, it will be blank.